# Javascript String utility library that plays nicely

Tags: jquery, string, prototype

For a longer time I have pondered why there aren't more robust Javascript string utility libraries that have developer friendly APIs. I have been spoiled by the Rails frameworks with sugary utility methods like:

> camelcase, camelize, classify, constantize, dasherize, deconstantize, demodulize, humanize, isBlank, parameterize, pluralize, tableize, titlecase, titleize, underscore

I note that some of these you can easily find one-off implementations of but most implementations are painful to use with other JS libraries since they usually use a nasty form of prototypal inheritance that drops any additions libraries like Jquery or Prototype make to the prototype.

Have I been living in a closet for the last decade, who has the magic here? I am not really looking for examples of how to implement, but for a library that works with jQuery and other toys I already have in the box.

Comment: Whilst useless for String manipulation, you may find [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) a useful collection of utility functions (coincidentally, for everything *other* than strings :P).

Comment: Sounds like a good opportunity for someone to write a new library.  How about you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [UNDERSCORE STRING](http://epeli.github.com/underscore.string/)

> Underscore.string is JavaScript library for comfortable manipulation
>   with strings, extension for Underscore.js inspired by Prototype.js,
>   Right.js, Underscore and beautiful Ruby language.
>
> Underscore.string provides you several useful functions: capitalize,
>   clean, includes, count, escapeHTML, unescapeHTML, insert, splice,
>   startsWith, endsWith, titleize, trim, truncate and so on.

Answer (score 0):

[underscore.string](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string#readme) may do the trick.

```
var result = _.string.reverse("I love to teach the world");
alert(result)
```

[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/VLyJd/)

Comment: Says you can use it with our without underscore.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I've read it. Thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

Yet another neat String library is here : **[String JS](http://stringjs.com/)** It extends the String prototype and works flawlessly on all browsers (and even with Node.JS)